# A função "valorApagar()" não me retorna o resultado correto

Tags: php, funções

Tenho o seguinte enunciado:

> Um estacionamento cobra uma taxa mínima de R$2,00 para estacionar por
>   três horas. Um adicional de R$0,50 por hora não necessariamente
>   inteira é cobrado após as três primeiras horas. O valor máximo para
>   qualquer dado período de 24 horas é R$10,00. Suponha que nenhum carro
>   fica estacionado por mais de 24 horas por vez. Escreva um aplicativo
>   que calcule e exiba as taxas do estacionamento para cada cliente que
>   estacionou nessa garagem ontem.  Você deve inserir as horas de
>   estacionamento para cada cliente. O programa deve exibir a cobrança
>   para o cliente atual e calcular e exibir o total recebido no final do
>   dia. O programa deve usar uma função valorAPagar para determinar a
>   cobrança para cada cliente.

Isso foi o que eu tentei fazer:

```
   <?php 
    if ($_POST) {
        $t = $_POST['num-hor'];
        $total = valorApagar($t);
        echo"<br><br>Total: R$".number_format($total, 2, ',', '.');

    }
    function valorApagar($t){
        $total = 0;

        if ($t <= 3) {
            $total = 2;
        }else if ($t > 3 && $t < 24) {
            $total = 2; 
            $t -= 3;
            if(is_int($t) == true){
                $total += $t;
            }else{
                $t = ceil($t);
                $t *= 0.5;
                $total += $t;
            }
        }else {
            $total = 10;
        }

        return $total;
    }
 ?>
```

A função `valorApagar()` não está me retornando o resultado correto, como ajusta-la para retornar o resultado de acordo com que é pedido no enunciado?

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Answer (score 4):

> O problema é muito mais matematico do que de programação. Além disso a pergunta não está clara sobre o problema, tornando quase uma terceirização de serviço.  Porém como é fácil e simples de resolver irei responder, **mesmo que talvez não deva**.

Você deve apenas usar:

```
$total = 2 + ((ceil($t) - 3)  * 0.5);
```

Porém existem outros erros no PHP. A sua pergunta diz que "*por hora não necessariamente inteira*", portanto se alguém estacionar por 23 horas e 10 minutos irá pagar por 24 horas?! No meu entendimento é isso.

Portanto, corrigindo tudo:

```
if(isset($_POST['num-hor'])){
    echo 'Total: R$'.(number_format( valorApagar( $_POST['num-hor'] ), 2, ',', '.'));
}

function valorApagar($t){
    $t = ceil($t);

    if($t <= 3){
        $total = 2;
    }else if ($t > 3 && $t < 24) {  
        $total = 2 + (($t - 3)  * 0.5); 
    }else {
        $total = 10;
    }

    return $total;
}
```

[Teste isso aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc192bffc7a04b24ca1849c461a096cbc5a6baf0)

Resultado:

```
0 horas custam R$2,00
1 horas custam R$2,00
2 horas custam R$2,00
3 horas custam R$2,00
4 horas custam R$2,50
5 horas custam R$3,00
6 horas custam R$3,50
7 horas custam R$4,00
8 horas custam R$4,50
9 horas custam R$5,00
10 horas custam R$5,50
11 horas custam R$6,00
12 horas custam R$6,50
13 horas custam R$7,00
14 horas custam R$7,50
15 horas custam R$8,00
16 horas custam R$8,50
17 horas custam R$9,00
18 horas custam R$9,50
19 horas custam R$10,00
20 horas custam R$10,50
21 horas custam R$11,00
22 horas custam R$11,50
23 horas custam R$12,00
24 horas custam R$10,00
25 horas custam R$10,00
```

Resultado antigo (seu código):

```
0 horas custam R$2,00
1 horas custam R$2,00
2 horas custam R$2,00
3 horas custam R$2,00
4 horas custam R$3,00
5 horas custam R$4,00
6 horas custam R$5,00
7 horas custam R$6,00
8 horas custam R$7,00
9 horas custam R$8,00
10 horas custam R$9,00
11 horas custam R$10,00
12 horas custam R$11,00
13 horas custam R$12,00
14 horas custam R$13,00
15 horas custam R$14,00
16 horas custam R$15,00
17 horas custam R$16,00
18 horas custam R$17,00
19 horas custam R$18,00
20 horas custam R$19,00
21 horas custam R$20,00
22 horas custam R$21,00
23 horas custam R$22,00
24 horas custam R$10,00
25 horas custam R$10,00
```

Resultados obtidos usando:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 26; $i++){
    echo $i.' horas custam R$'.(number_format( valorApagar( $i ), 2, ',', '.'))."\n";
}
```

Comment: Como ficaria se a função recebesse a hora de entrada e o minuto de entrada separados e também a hora e o minuto de saida?

Answer (score 3):

Segue uma versão "curta" só para complementar a postagem.

Fiz com base na [resposta do @inkeliz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148113/70) (que, por sinal, é muito mais didática pra quem está aprendendo, e já levou meu +1):

```
function valorAPagar($t) {
    return min( 10, max( 2, ceil( $t ) / 2 + .5 ) );
};
```

- usamos apenas a fórmula `ceil( $t ) / 2 + .5`, já que o resultado é linear.
  ( É apenas uma simplificação de `2 + ( ($t - 3)  * 0.5 )` )
- o `min( 10, valor )` faz com que não passe de 10
- da mesma forma, `max( 2, valor )` faz com que o valor seja no mínimo 2

Veja um *loop* de teste no **[Online PHP Functions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c7622c719da21edcd0ce4b0c7f54b8b92b87424)**.

Comment: Ok, gostei mesmo do "one line". [+1]